# \newcommand for the row numbering

Tags: tables, macros

I want to have an automatic numbering of the rows in my table and I have a command for that, but it doesn't work correctly and I don't know how to fix it. Can someone help me to rewrite it?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[russian]{babel}  % Включаем пакет для поддержки русского
\usepackage{multirow,tabularx}
\usepackage[a4paper,margin=1in,landscape]{geometry}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\newcounter{rowcnt}

\newcommand\rownum{\ifnumequal{\value{rowcnt}}{0}{№}{\therowcnt.}\refstepcounter{rowcnt}}
\AtEndEnvironment{tabularx}{\setcounter{rowcnt}{0}}

\begin{document}

\renewcommand\arraystretch{1.333}
\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{|>{\rownum}l|>{\hspace{0pt}}p{2.2cm}|l|>{\hspace{0pt}}p{2cm}|X|l|}\hline
& Описание отклонения & Департамент & Идентифицированный риск & Не
идентифицированный риск \\\hline
\endhead
  & Deviation 1 &    Отдел IT   &  Доллар = 1 гривне   & \textbf{Описание не идентифицированого риска:} \newline   risk 1 description risk 2 description\\ \cline{5-5}
    &           &           &           &  \textbf{Объект в котором появился этот риск:} \newline   Холодильная установка Sumsung FG5647   Склад №3    \\\hline
 & Deviation 2&    Отдел ВЭД   &  ид риск 1   & \textbf{Описание не идентифицированого риска:} \newline    \\ \cline{5-5}
        &           &           &           &  \textbf{Объект в котором появился этот риск:} \newline    \\\hline
    \end{tabularx}

    \end{document}
```

[image]

What I want to have is:
[image]

Comment: The posted code produces `! Undefined control sequence.
l.8 \AtEndEnvironment` and `! Missing number, treated as zero.
<to be read again> 
                   \c@rowcnt ` and `! Undefined control sequence.
<recently read> \endhead 
`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you get TeX errors you should fix those rather than looking at the output (TeX does not try to make sensible output after an error) Similarly if you are asking about errors, show the error code not an image of the output.

Here you haven't loaded `etoolbox` so you get undefined command errors, and haven't declared the counter that you use, and have used a command `\endhead` that isn't defined (I just deleted it).

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[russian]{babel}  % Включаем пакет для поддержки русского
\usepackage{multirow,tabularx}
\usepackage[a4paper,margin=1in,landscape]{geometry}

\usepackage{etoolbox}
\newcounter{rowcnt}

\newcommand\rownum{\ifnumequal{\value{rowcnt}}{0}{№}{\therowcnt.}\refstepcounter{rowcnt}}
\AtEndEnvironment{tabularx}{\setcounter{rowcnt}{0}}

\begin{document}

\renewcommand\arraystretch{1.333}
\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{|>{\rownum}l|>{\hspace{0pt}}p{2.2cm}|l|>{\hspace{0pt}}p{2cm}|X|l|}\hline
& Описание отклонения & Департамент & Идентифицированный риск & Не
идентифицированный риск \\\hline
  & Deviation 1 &    Отдел IT   &  Доллар = 1 гривне   & \textbf{Описание не идентифицированого риска:} \newline   risk 1 description risk 2 description\\ \cline{5-5}
    &           &           &           &  \textbf{Объект в котором появился этот риск:} \newline   Холодильная установка Sumsung FG5647   Склад №3    \\\hline
 & Deviation 2&    Отдел ВЭД   &  ид риск 1   & \textbf{Описание не идентифицированого риска:} \newline    \\ \cline{5-5}
        &           &           &           &  \textbf{Объект в котором появился этот риск:} \newline    \\\hline
    \end{tabularx}

    \end{document}
```

Comment: yeah, you are right, I forgot about packages and new counter. But I'm also curious how to make a correct numeration, so right now I have  №1, 2 in the first row, and then  № 3  and 4 in the second one. I want to have 1 in the first row and 2 in the second row. How to do it?

Comment: @Lucky_girl if you always generate the posted image with the code you are posting then it would not be possible to forget packages. As you have marked up the table the numbering is correct you have 1 in the first row, 2 in the second.  The second row is empty apart from the last column.

Comment: @Lucky_girl If you want the numbering to be just 1,2 best would be just to have that many rows, and use a multi-line entry in the last column, however the simplest change would be to use `\multicolumn{1}{l}{}` in first column cells where you do not want a number.